# How to give rating in listview

Tags: android

I am doing listview with multiple choice,(this listview is not a customized) and more i want to include rating option to my listview. i googled, but i dint get any proper solution. can anyone give me a suggestion for how to do this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include a [RatingBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) widget inside your custom row layouts.

Comment: Thank you for immediate replies.. Can you explain me in brief.

Comment: You'll need a custom list view, no way to do it with standard adapter/row layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to include RatingBar widget inside each row. You can see the example [here](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aqhnAEPhtjjkJ%3acommonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf+rating+in+listview+in+android&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgIPB_CBr2EaqoVBTDGQ-mkY-rulPiNjxhAaJnpf6hR-ztlR7Qf8VmaUNf7nX9Y-xaV3QDYSGEJLF7nhdEXtD3pEwI1yBc_qTKaz6bJQRjNDTZDyYrXLNMlWoOwbMb4lzdjmeQW&sig=AHIEtbTxGAPqFX_KDkefgWHBWZ9hsspJIQ). I think this is what you want.

Comment: Actually i am not using customized listview. is there any way to include Ratings in non customized list view..?? pls guide me...

Comment: I think you have to use customized listview. Because it allows only string array to be displayed in simple listview. I mean only string in each row. There is no list row layout with rating bar. You have to implement it by your own.

Comment: Hey you will have to go for custom list view. You cannot do this task with non customized list.